# Can't extend OnClickListener - what's an alternative?

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to Android. In my activities when I need to detect a tap on a button I implement OnClickListener. In my current Activity I have to implement 'YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener' so I can't extend OnClickListener. How do I detect click events?

Comment: OnClickListener is an interface, so you can implement this interface. A class can implement more than one interface.

Comment: You don't EXTENDS onClickListener, you IMPLEMENT it just to override the methods of the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `View.OnClickListener` is an `interface`. you havo to `implements` it, not `extend`. Java does not support extending from multiple class, but you can implement multiple interfaces

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. How do I implement multiple interfaces? It didn't seem possibly after looking around Google. Edit: got it. Thanks.

Comment: you have to add the implements keyword once and separate by comma the interface you want to implement

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
{
   //Your code here

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);


    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(button))
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id_in_xml);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Do your stuffs   

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else said, `OnClickListener` is an interface so you'll have to *implement* it, not extend. But if you're still looking for an alternative, try using it as an anonymous inner class:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
          //do stuff when clicked
     }
}
)
```